# How to query value of column that is set as pointer to other table in Parse

Tags: java, android, parsing, parse-platform

I am using [Parse](http://parse.com) for my app. I want to query a table with column that set to be a pointer to other table. Here is the query:

```
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("CategoryAttribute");
        query.whereEqualTo("categoryId", categoryId);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> categoryAttributes, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < categoryAttributes.size(); i++){
                        String atributeCategoryId = categoryAttributes.get(i).getString("categoryId");
                        String attributeKey  = categoryAttributes.get(i).getString("attributeKey");
                        String attributeValue   = categoryAttributes.get(i).getString("attributeValue");

                        setCategoryAtributeRow(atributeCategoryId, attributeKey, attributeValue);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
```

So the `categoryId` column is a pointer to other table. Other columns work fine.
I tried to scan the API and the guides but couldn't find needed solution. Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you find any solution of this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is the solution to this one:

First you need to create a `ParseObject` from the type of your table:

```
ParseObject sale = ParseObject.createParseObject("Sale");
```

Then you need to get the `ParseObject` from the result:

```
sale = result.getParseObject(pointer_field);
```

Now you can pull from `sale` any field that it has just as you would do it normally, for example:

```
sale.getString("some_field")
```

**Note:**
When you are doing your query you must to include the pointer field if you want to be able to extract the data from it after the query will be returned. The result:

```
query.include("pointer_field")
```

Hope it helps

Comment: @Jaffar Raza here is the answer

Comment: Could you give a hint on how to do this using javascript?

Comment: @AkshatAgarwal, Sorry I don't know how to do this in javascript. But I am sure it is very similar.

Comment: can't get you !!! see i have a field username that is pointer to "User" and i want to query it with that pointer only !! can you suggest me ?????

Comment: They should have included it in their documentation! Great solution!

Answer (score 4):

@Akshat Agarwal, here is a example in JavaScript:

```
var parseObj = Parse.Object.extend('parseObj');

new Parse.Query(parseObj)
  .include('pointerField')
  .find(function (data) {
    data.get('pointerField').get('fieldName');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS

```
  PFQuery *parseQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MyClass"];
  [parseQuery whereKey:@"categoryId" equalTo:categoryId];
  [parseQuery includeKey:@"pinter_field"];
  [parseQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
  //
  }];
```