# Query with pointer User in Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, pfquery

I am using Parse.com in my app, I have created a "Post" class and inside I have a pointer that specifies which user sent the post. Now I seeing on the timeline to the Post and the time the user name who created the post. Since the user is a pointer I can not make a correct query, do you know how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to use `PFQuery includeKey` to have the related pointer data automatically filled by Parse.
The `user` data will be downloaded without requiring you to make another query for it.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"];

// Include the user data with each post
[query includeKey:@"title_of_userpointer_column"];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *postObjects, NSError *error)
 {
     if (!error) {
         NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved: %d items", [postObjects count]);

         // postObjects now contains the latest 100 Posts, and the "title_of_userpointer_column" field
         // has been populated.
         // For example:
         for (PFObject * postObject in postObjects) {

             // This does not require a network access.
             PFObject *postAuthor = [postObject objectForKey:@"title_of_userpointer_column"];
             NSLog(@"retrieved related Post Author: %@", postAuthor);
         }
 }
```

Comment: I'll delete this comment soon, but could you help me here?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33606788/swift-how-to-get-parses-many-users-name-and-photo

Answer (score 4):

You can retrieve the pointer to User field from the Post table by adding this line of code (in Android):

`postQuery.include("pointerToUser");`

`postQuery` is query of class `Post`. By this way, after executing the query the object or objects that will be returned would have the user information.

You can see a full example here:
[How to query value of column that is set as pointer to other table in Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517541/how-to-query-value-of-column-that-set-as-pointer-to-other-table-in-parse/16954785#16954785)

Comment: @VladIoffe - do you have an answer for doing the same in javascript?

Comment: @Akshat Agarwal I think it is the same. Try to write your question and I will try to help.

Comment: @vlio20  can u tell me i m facing isue in android how to save ppointer of User table in installation table using parse.com in android
in installation table there is this snapshot imgur.com/lShguu5 a pointer of User table i.e objectiD OF user where as object id of user i m getting at the time of sign up of user see this imgur.com/6P7ggQs 
now i m failed to save pointer user in installation table
imgur.com/6P7ggQs imgur.com/lShguu5