# Using pointers with Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, parse-platform

I'm currently developing my first App. The App is a Basic messenger App based on Parse.com.

I want to create a `PFQueryTableViewController` where it will show the recent chats with other users.

`Photo` of other user, `Name` of other user and `timestamp` (similar to Facebook messanger "recent" tab).

the chats data is saved in a Parse Class named `Room` with the following columns:

1. objectid(string)
2. roomname(string)
3. User_1(pointer to _User)
4. User_2(pointer to _User)...

I can fill the table view easily with the string values (e.g the roomname) but I would like to get the users `@"full name"` as the Label of each cell.

this is my code (I get an empty TableView):

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Room"];
    [query includeKey:@"User_2"];

    if (self.objects.count == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }

    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

    return query;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                        object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    PFTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[PFTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = object[@"fullname"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099137/query-with-pointer-user-in-parse-com but its not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

When the pointer object is initially available it's just a stub, it doesn't actually contain any data. You need to call `fetchAllIfNeededInBackground:block:` on it (them, to keep things efficient) to populate the data.

Look at subclassing the table view controller and overriding `- (void)objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error` to trigger the fetch on the new objects.

Note that you might just want to change your `Room` class to cache the user names (though if you do that you will need some cloud code to update the caches if the user name changes).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. but im not sure i understand. Could you maybe provide an example (its my first week learning how to code), Thank you.

Comment: What specifically don't you understand? When using pointers you don't immediately have the info you need, you need to make an additional request to get it. The table controller will only get your `Room` objects data, you need to additionally request the data for the users that they point to.

Comment: That i understand, but i'm not sure how to request the additional information.I tried adding this under the includeKey query:

**[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *postObjects, NSError *error)** {
     
    if (self.objects.count == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }
    
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    
    return query;
    }
     ]};

But got an Error: incompatible block pointer types....

Comment: You need to get the `objects` from the table controller and use them in a call to `fetchAllIfNeededInBackground:block:`. This is separate to the query that you give to the controller and after that query has returned data...

Comment: Seems there are a few subjects i need to learn before i can continue. Thanks for the Help. I will be back with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it, hope this helps others.
This is the updated working code:

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Room"];
[query includeKey:@"User_2"];

// If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
// and then subsequently do a query against the network.
if (self.objects.count == 0) {
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
}

[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

return query;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                    object:(PFObject *)object
{

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

PFTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[PFTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                  reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}



PFObject *user = object[@"User_2"];

[user fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *user, NSError *error) {
    //NSLog(@"%@", user);

    cell.textLabel.text = user[@"fullname"];
}];

return cell;
}

@end
```