# Parse.com Android get object and relation with ParseUser

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have this code in Android:

```
            ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
            user.setUsername(email.getText().toString().trim());
            user.setPassword(password.getText().toString().trim());
            user.setEmail(email.getText().toString().trim());
            user.pinInBackground();
            user.saveInBackground();
            ParseObject UserProfile = new ParseObject("UserProfile");
            UserProfile.put("Name", name.getText().toString().trim());
            UserProfile.put("UserMobile", mobile.getText().toString().trim());
            UserProfile.saveInBackground();
            UserProfile.pinInBackground();
```

This code working fine but how I can get data from Parse class UserProfile and how I can relate ParseUser with UserProfile?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just create a 'pointer' field in your user table.
After this you can put a pointer to the profile in your user table

```
user.put(userprofile)
```

Comment: How I can get data from UserProfile? like Name, Mobile?

Comment: Take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517541/how-to-query-value-of-column-that-is-set-as-pointer-to-other-table-in-parse

Comment: Still I don't get it. How I link it and how I can get data for user from UserProfile?

Answer (score 0):

You can link two objects using a pointer. To do that just add

```
user.put("CurrentUser",userprofile);
```

Also make a "CurrentUser" pointer field in your table.

You can access userprofile data by:

```
user.getParseObject("CurrentUser").fetch().get("Name");
```